# how to render infopath webpage in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

how to render infopath webpage in sharepoint.

I have designed the MS office infopath form, & stored in the my sharepoint site document library, (in fact i created new one). But when i want to open that form it direct redirect in MS office infopath with running form. Which i don't want. I want to open form in sharepoint site. How it is possible . Please guide me ....

Comment: no one can answer ? please help me .... & please don't suggest use webpart. I want exceptional way to do so....

Answer (score 0):

The ability to display InfoPath natively in a browser is part of InfoPath Forms Services, which is only provided bundled with MOSS Enterprise, not MOSS Standard or the free WSS.

Forms Server is available as a separate license altogether as well, but there's no other mechanism to display InfoPath forms in a browser without rolling your own solution, which would be a rather complex undertaking.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Now i able to do what i wanted. but some controls cannot see in the browsers. this means not compatible the infopath form. I followed some steps to do so as
1)in infopath, in tool bar -> Tools -> Form Options ->Compatibility ->checked the option "Design a form template that can be opened in a browser or infopath "but problem still remaining that can not see some controls in browsers. I have version of browsers IE 6.0.3790.3959, mozila 3.0.14. what i have to do to achieve this?

Comment: What controls are you having problems with? Unfortunately, some controls simply have no HTML analogue and are incompatible in browser based forms (text boxes set to expand all, for example). If you enter Form Options -> Compatibility in the InfoPath designer and check the "Design a form template that can be opened in a browser or InfoPath" box your design surface should automatically limit you from adding controls incompatible with browser based forms.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish the form to a forms library or did you simply upload it?  In order for Forms Services to render a form it must be published using InfoPath's File>>Publish command.